Has any research linked gestational period and exhibited mourning behavior? If so, how?
While reading the National Geographic Answer Book (2016ce), I was reminded elephants have a gestation period of a little less than two years.  Mourning behaviors for these creatures may include "sleep disturbance" and "increased stress." Chimpanzees and Japanese macaques may also show similar behaviors (gestations of 8 months and 171 days, respectively.)
The bottlenose dolphin has a gestation period of about 12 months.
Are you aware if the walrus and the white rhinoceros mourn the dead in their lives?  Both of these animals have long gestation periods.
Are any animals with long gestation periods not demonstrating these behaviors?
If any research has been conducted to link gestation or 'mothering' times to mourning behavior, how was this research conducted?  If not, how would you imagine we may best conduct this research?
Thank you.

How would you connect these? And what makes you certain to have "correlation and not causation"?

Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] to find how this site works and the Help on asking questions. You ask ask "us" how we would conduct research on a topic of interest to you, but we require posters to do their own research before asking questions. First, you might state that you have searched for "correlation of gestation period with mourning behaviour" and found nothing. However, more to the point, you need to show you have thought about the problem of determining when correlation implies causation. You will find this on the internet.

@Chris Hate to argue in the comments, but not all science is done in the lab. observational and correlation studies are legitimate science and can be quite useful in biology and other sciences. Especially when it comes to fields like wild-life biology, ecology, and animal behavior; where experimentalists are probably in the minority. Also, like, the vast majority of epidemiology research is based in observational studies, though it's maybe more common for epidemiologists to engage in both observational and experimental research, given the opportunity.

The field of study you're looking for is called comparative thanatology. Start with literature search on Google Scholar or another research repository, and use what you find to narrow the focus of this question.
I can think of some counterexamples already, but that doesn't mean there's not a trend. Domestic dogs seem to mourn each other, yet have relatively short gestation. Several Corvid species display what appear to be mourning behaviors, but how would compare compare egg incubation times with mammalian gestation?

Questions like this make me worry about the proper scaling of the measurements. After all, time could be viewed as relative to a) expected lifespan, b) expected fertility, c) body size, or more complex measures. "Year" or "month" are human created measurements, for all that they may have certain natural correlates, and do not represent non-human animal experiences of time. The proper unit of measure is not obvious without a supporting literature.

You don't state it, but presumably you mean higher animals, mammals, birds etc.. Creatures like ragworms have a phenomenally long gestation, but not much by way of a brain to process attachment and grief. What's your area of interest?
